# Easy way to unfollow users not also following me?

Tags: twitter, followers

On Twitter, is there an easy way to unfollow users not also following me – or at least get a list of such users I'm following where there isn't reciprocation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out http://friendorfollow.com

Answer (score 2):

One great option is http://www.tweepsect.com/

In addition to showing you people that don't follow you back, it also has an easy way to follow or unfollow people directly from its interface. The downside is that it requires you to log in, whereas friendorfollow.com does not.

Comment: On the bright side, thanks to logging in, you also get to follow and unfollow people right from the Tweepsect interface. :)

Answer (score 1):

[WhoUnfollowedMe](http://who.unfollowed.me/), one of those unfollower-trackers, also shows a list of people you follow that aren't following you back.

It also offers unfollowing directly from their interface.

Answer (score 1):

http://refollow.com/ is best for managing friends and followers

Answer (score 0):

A very simple website that allows you to do this is [Twitter Karma](http://dossy.org/twitter/karma/). You can see who are following you and you're not following, who are you following and isn't following, and some other options...

It allows *Bulk follow*, *Bulk block*, and used to provide a *Bulk unfollow* feature too, but it is no longer  available because it is against [*Twitter's Automation Rules and Best Practices*](http://dossy.org/twitter/karma/).

It currently allows you to manual follow/unfollow users by one click.

Answer (score 0):

I use twidium [http://twidiumapp.com/](http://twidiumapp.com) It has four important features I need – mass following, list following, unfollowing and the project planner.

Answer (score 0):

I use Managefillter, it is very good tool to unfollow them who are not following you back. I mentioned 10 best twitter unfollow tools at my blog updateland.com. Check out these 10 best [twitter unfollow tools](https://www.updateland.com/twitter-unfollow-tools-non-followers/). I hope you will find them good. You can easily unfollow using these tools with single click. Here is the list.

1. Follow Filter
2. Crowdfireapp
3. Tweepi
4. UnfollowSpy
5. Unfollowers.com
6. ManageFlitter
7. iUnfollow
8. Twitter Karma
9. UnfollowerStats
10. SocialBro