# Is there a right way to unfollow Twitter users?

Tags: twitter

I get the sense that the follow-back ratio is important, and I would like to unfollow users that don't follow my account, but not sure what is the best way to do this.

Guess the other thing is I really have not figured out a good way to know if someone I follow will follow back more than the average follow back ratio; meaning people that just follow anyone.

Comment: Closely related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/299/twitter-easy-way-to-unfollow-users-not-also-following-me?rq=1

Comment: @Al Everett: Agree it's related, though it doesn't touch on "the right way" to unfollow users; meaning it's my understanding that some patterns of unfollowing users will have a negative effect on your account, maybe even result in your account getting flagged with a warning or banned.

Comment: I doubt there is a "right" way. They've given the tools to (un)follow accounts and unless you're using those tools to do some sort of Denial of Service then how can you be misusing them? Then again, I'm just an occasional Twitter user; I'm not using it for any sort of social marketing strategy. If this really is a concern (getting account dinged) then perhaps you should be asking the Twitter people.

Comment: Here's how I decide whom to follow: - If I find someone interesting, I follow them. - If I find someone uninteresting, I don't follow them. - If I am following somebody and I find that I no longer find them interesting, I stop following them. Reasons people should follow me: - I say things they find interesting. Reasons people should not follow me: - They want me to follow them back. Life is too short to worry about ratios. Be more concerned with what you're saying, producing, and creating. If it's interesting to people, they will follow. If it's not interesting to them, why would you want the

Comment: @downvoter: While I value your opinion, without a comment to explain the downvote there's no way for me to attempt address your concerns. Thanks!

Comment: @Al Everett: Yes, you will get banned, or a warning, if you bulk unfollow users in some ways, and Twitter will not clearly state what those ways are...

Comment: The second half of your question, devising a strategy for knowing who to follow and who not is beyond the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of tools out there that can give you this information. [ManageFlitter](http://www.manageflitter.com) is one.

Among other things, it can tell you who you follow who doesn't follow you as well as who follows you that you don't follow. It also provides tools to make it easier to follow/unfollow in bulk.

Comment: +1 Thanks, looking at the "free" version right now, though it looks like I'm already finding some issues. For example, there's a user that's not following me, but the user retweeted a tweet of mine, and created an account on my site; meaning it would be unwise to unfollow them in my opinion, and it does not appears that ManageFlitter is checking for something as important as retweets. Still looks good so far, and better than nothing.